# How to predict class probabilities？

Tags: python, keras, predict

I trained a cat and dog classification model, and when I did, I didn't know how to get the probability of each category

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, mate?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to have two neurons at the top of your network.
so after the convolutional layers:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3,img_rows,img_cols),dim_ordering="th"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```